# Totally decomposable vectors as quotient of monomorphisms by SL

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, monomorphisms

Consider vector spaces $V$ and $W$ of dimensions $m$ and $n\geq m$, respectively.
Both the special linear group $\operatorname{SL}(V)$ as well as the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ act smoothly and freely from the right on the smooth manifold of monomorphism $\operatorname{Mono}(V;W)$ by precomposition. Denote the space of totally decomposable $m$-vectors in $W$ by $\bigwedge^m_sW$.

Fix a basis $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ of $V$ and define the surjective map
$$\pi\colon \operatorname{Mono}(V;W)\to \bigwedge\nolimits^m_sW\setminus\{0\}, A\mapsto Ae_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge Ae_m.$$
I can show that the map
$\Phi\colon \operatorname{Mono}(V;W)/\operatorname{SL}(V) \to \bigwedge^m_sW\setminus\{0\}$ defined by $\Phi([A]_{\operatorname{SL}}) = \pi(A)$ is well-defined and bijective.
Analoguously, I can show that $\Psi\colon \operatorname{Mono}(V;W)/\operatorname{GL}(V) \to \bigwedge^m_sW\setminus\{0\}$ defined by $\Phi([A]_{\operatorname{GL}}) = \{t \pi(A)\colon t\in\mathbb{R}^{\times}\}$ is well-defined and bijective.
Hence the following diagram commutes:

[image: Diagram]

My main issue is whether $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are diffeomorphisms. To even start to show this each space should be a smooth manifold.
I know that by the Plücker embedding $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^m_sW\setminus\{0\})$ is the Grassmannian and thus a compact smooth manifold of dimension $m(n-m)$.
The quotient on the bottom right also should have dimension $nm-m^2=m(n-m)$ but I'm unsure how to show that it's a smooth manifold. If $\operatorname{GL}$ acted properly then the quotient manifold theorem would be my friend. Is this the case?

The quotient on the middle right should have dimension $nm-(m^2-1)=m(n-m)+1$. The totally decomposable $m$-vectors are a projective variety of "non-projective" dimension $m(n-m)+1$. So these arguments at least indicate to me, thankfully, that my bijectivity proofs are not bogus.
I'm unsure if the spaces on the middle level are actually manifolds. On this level, also, the map $\pi$ does depend on the chosen basis whereas (an analogous map) on the bottom level does not. Maybe another indication that the bottom-level compactification makes things "better"?

What "regularity" of $\Phi$ could I even expect? I want to show that the totally decomposable vectors are isomorphic to the middle right quotient in an appropriate category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the tautological (rank-$m$) vector bundle over the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(m,W)$ and let
$$
P := \mathrm{Iso}(V,U)
$$
be the corresponding principal $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-bundle over $\mathrm{Gr}(m,W)$. Then
$$
P \cong \mathrm{Mono}(V;W).
$$
Indeed, the map from left to right is given by taking an isomorphism $V \to U$ to the composition $V \to U \to W$, where the second arrow is the tautological embedding, and it is easy to see this map is an isomorphism and, moreover, it is $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-equivariant. Taking quotients by $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ and $\mathrm{SL}(V)$, you can obtain the two isomorphism you are interested in.

Comment: 1. So $U$ is the bundle whose fibre at a point $E\in\operatorname{Gr}(m,W)$ is just $E$ itself and I have to interpret $P$ as the bundle whose fiber at $E\in\operatorname{Gr}(m,W)$ is $\operatorname{Iso}(V;E)$. Is that correct? 
2. As a principle $\operatorname{GL}(V)$-bundle over $\operatorname{Gr}(m,W)$ its quotient by $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is simply $\operatorname{Gr}(m,W)$. Why is its quotient by $\operatorname{SL}(V)$ the set of totally decomposable $m$-vectors?

Comment: 3. My main issue actually was which regularity the quotients and the isomorphisms have. The isomorphisms on the quotient by $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ will be a diffeo by your answer. What about the regularity of the isomorphism on the quotient by $\operatorname{SL}(V)$?

Comment: 1 is OK. For 2 choose a non-zero element $\delta \in \wedge^mV$ and consider the map $P \to \wedge W$ that takes an isomorphism $V \to E$, raises it to the $m$-th wedge power, and applies to $\delta$ (thus obtaining an element of $\wedge^mE \subset \wedge^mW$). It is equivariant for the action of $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ (the stabilizer of $\delta$) and induces an isomorphism of the quotient by it with the set of totally decomposable vectors. As for 3 --- the point of this construction is that instead of quotients you study principle bundles, for which there question of regularity is completely clear.

Comment: So the map $P\to \wedge^m W$ does exactly the same as the map $\pi$ in my construction above. Could you elaborate on the question of regularity a bit further; since it is, unfortunately, still unclear to me? The principal $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-bundle $P\to \mathrm{Gr}(m,W)$ is a bundle over a smooth manifold, the principal $\mathrm{SL}(V)$-bundle $P\to \wedge^m_sW$ is a bundle over an algebraic variety. In which regularity category is this isomorphism on the base space/$\mathrm{SL}(V)$-quotient $\wedge^m_sW$ described above? Maybe I'm missing something very trivial?

Comment: The action of $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ on $P$ is free, hence the quotient is smooth and isomorphic to the variety of decomposable vectors.